# Duda sobre manejo de flex-box

Tags: html, css, css3, responsive, flexbox

En una parte de un curso de flex-box que estoy aprendiendo, la persona que lo esta explicando al momento de utilizar `flex-direction: column` en el
código sus artículos no se le desbordan del cuadro gris:

[image: Adjunto imagen]

Pero en mi caso, sí se desbordan del cuadro, ¿hay algo que estoy
aplicando mal o alguna recomendación que pueda utilizar?. Agredezco sus respuestas.

```css
html {
  padding: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: thin solid #FF5700;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Flex Box</title>

<body>
  <h1>Flex Box</h1>
  <section class="container">
    <article class="item">
      <h2>1</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
      <h2>2</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
      <h2>3</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
      <h2>4</h2>
    </article>
    <article class="item">
      <h2>5</h2>
    </article>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se te desborda porque tienes un `height` fijo y el contenido de dentro es mas alto que el de tu `.container`. Eliminando ese `height: 800px;` ya queda bien.

```css
html{
   padding: 2rem;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 16px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .container{
   /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
   margin: 1rem auto;
   padding: 1rem;
   width: 800px;

   background-color: #CCC;
   border: thin solid #FF5700;
        
   display: flex;
        
   flex-direction: column;
         
  }

  .item{
   /*box-sizing: border-box;*/
   margin: 1rem;
   width: 250px;
   height: 100px;
   text-align: center;
   color: #FFF;
   background-color: #222;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Flex Box</title>
 
<body>
 <h1>Flex Box</h1>
 <section class="container">
  <article class="item">
   <h2>1</h2>
  </article>
  <article class="item">
   <h2>2</h2>
  </article>
  <article class="item">
   <h2>3</h2>
  </article>
  <article class="item">
   <h2>4</h2>
  </article>
  <article class="item">
   <h2>5</h2>
  </article>
 </section>
 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Como aclaración: los `800px` son del `width`, no del `height`